# reset button click dosent work in custom angular reactive form

Tags: angular, forms, customization, angular-reactive-forms

Good morning all,
I have a problem with the reset button which does not work for all fields with the custom form control, I use reactive form!
attached an example:

**Parent component TS**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  templateUrl: 'parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['parent.component.css'],
})
export class ParentComponent {



}
```

**Parent Component HTML**

```
<child-component > </chield-component>
```

**Child Component TS**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
 
 
  form: FormGroup;
 
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }
 
  countries = [
    { id: 1, name: "United States" },
    { id: 2, name: "Australia" },
    { id: 3, name: "Canada" },
    { id: 4, name: "Brazil" },
    { id: 5, name: "England" }
  ];
 
  ngOnInit() {
 
    this.form = this.fb.group({      
    country : [''],
    town : ['']
   });
 
  submit() {
    console.log(this.form.value)
  }
}
```

**Child Component HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
 

 //this select have date from child component

  <select formControlName="country">
    <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [ngValue]="country.id">{{country.name}}</option>
  </select>

//this select have date from parent component

<select formControlName="town">
    <option *ngFor="let town of towns" [ngValue]="town.id">{{town.name}}</option>
  </select>


<button type="submit">Submit</button>
<button type="reset">Reset</button>

 
</form>
```

My question is houw can i reset all filed of this custom form knowing that one select have data from child component and one other form parant child !!
it's very complicated for me !
Thank you all

I tried all the reset methods but it doesn't work.

Comment: I do not see code for resert button

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one**

```
<button type="button" (click)="resetForm(form)">Reset</button>

resetForm = (form:FormGroup)=> {
 form.reset();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular `Reactive Forms` has a `reset` function which will do the job. And it's better you let do it Angular itself.

```
this.form.reset();
```

You can read more about it in the [official docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#reset).

Here is a [Stackblitz](https://angular-12-form-validation-y1ykx8.stackblitz.io) example.